# What are sensible semaphore numbers?

Tags: kernel

[What are semaphores and how are they caused?](https://serverfault.com/questions/139478/what-are-semaphores-and-how-are-they-caused) has a fairly good explanation of what semaphores are, but I'm not sure what my configuration should be. I recently ran into the same problem as that question, and when looking over the internet I found wildly different examples of what the new config should be. Here's a couple of examples:

On RHEL 7.2:

```
# cat /proc/sys/kernel/sem
250 32000 32 128
```

On Fedora 20:

```
# cat /proc/sys/kernel/sem
32000 1024000000 500 32000
```

Those are some crazy different numbers. What makes sense for a medium size server, and what are the downsides to larger numbers?

Comment: According to [RHEL Documentation](https://access.redhat.com/documentation/en-US/Red_Hat_Enterprise_Linux/5/html/Tuning_and_Optimizing_Red_Hat_Enterprise_Linux_for_Oracle_9i_and_10g_Databases/chap-Oracle_9i_and_10g_Tuning_Guide-Setting_Semaphores.html), you should probably consult the documentation for whatever applications you are hosting.